# Can DhtmlxGantt Component generate any kind of reports?

Tags: javascript, gantt-chart, dhtmlx

im currently working with DhtmlxGantt component. I was wondering if the DhtmlxGantt component itself can generate any kind of report? and If it can generate report, i would like to know the list for the types of reports it can generate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way to generate reports by Gantt, you need to implement a custom solution by using Gantt API and Javascript. Here is an example of how to show S-Curve with the help of ChartJS library:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/02_extensions/21_overlay.html

You can also check the resource load and resource histogram features:

https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__resource_management.html#resourceviewpanel
https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/11_resources/